# how to retain the text field value into the text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have an html table have 3 fields in which one of them is editable

- data for two columns i am getting as `json` those two fields are `itemName` and `itemCode` and the third column i am creating by myself `Quantity` for which i am giving value as 0
- i have a dropdown also which is `category` which have several dropdowns 1st is `All` initially its shows data for all
- after that if user clicks on`juice` which is category then only juice items get populated
- then user enters some quantity there and without saving goes to another category say `rice` and enters some quantity there also
- after this when user goes back to `juice` category the quantity he entered all goes and it shows as `0` which i don't want

i want to show the values which user enters even after he/she goes to any other category and comes back

- in simple i want to retain the values user once entered.
- i am making ajax call to populate the data inside table on the basis of `Category` selection

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({ //this ajax is populating for all categories

    url: "CategoryOlWiseFilter",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function(tableData) {
      addTable(tableData);
    }
  });

  $('#CategoryName').on('change', function() {
    var selectedOption = this.value;
    $.ajax({ //this one will populate which category is selected
      async: true,
      url: "ItemCategoryWiseFilter",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        categoryName: selectedOption,
      },
    });
    $.ajax({
      async: true,
      url: "ItemCategoryWiseFilter",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(tableData) {
        addTable(tableData);

      }
    });

  });


});

function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  var colNum = col.length; //to improve the speed
  for (var i = 0; i < colNum + 1; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    if (i >= colNum) {
      th.innerHTML = "Quantity";
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    } else {
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length + 1; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
      if (i > -1 && j >= colNum) {

        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "center";
        quantityField.setAttribute('name', 'Quantity');
        quantityField.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'on');
        quantityField.setAttribute('value', '0');
        quantityField.setAttribute('type', 'number');
        quantityField.setAttribute('required', 'required');
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      } else {

        if (tableData[i]['Item Code'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]['Item Name'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (j > 1)
          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="www.google.com" id="form1">
    <div class="row position-relative">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
        <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>juce</option>
          <option>rice</option>
          <option>roti</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="save">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>
      <button id="clear">
     <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> Clear
    </button>
      <button id="print" type="button" onclick="printFunction()">
     <i class="fas fa-print"></i> Print
    </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The json i am getting from back end is

```
    [{
    "Item Code": "1001",
    "Item Name": "Beverages",
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "2003",
    "Item Name": "Juices",
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1004",
    "Item Name": "Soups",
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "2005",
    "Item Name": "Cookies",
  },
]
```

quantity i am creating on `ui` so then i can store the values on change of dropdowns

i just want once user enter any quantity it should be there even if user goes to other dropdown and comes back

initial value i have to give `0` always

please guys help me ..i am stuck here from long time..not getting any idia how can i achieve that.
should i do it on `ui end` or `server end` but quantity is not coming from back end  that's why i have created it on client side

Please guys any kind of guidance like you should do like this you should do loke that would be very helpful please

Comment: Do you want to persist the entered values or just keep the values for the actual session?

Comment: @PabloDarde i dont know which will be better as i am very new to this..when user clicks on save then no need to store value

Comment: you could listen for changes on the input fields and then when a change is made, store the value in local storage.  e.g localStorage.setItem('juiceQuantity', juiceQuantity); then each time a category is selected, firstly check local storage to see if a value exists and if it does then insert the value to the input field.

Comment: Could you post a sample of the tableData  (for say the juices category) so I can try something out?

Comment: @sarah let say user clicks on juice then "[{
    "Item Code": "1056",
    "Item Name": "banana shake",
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "2883",
    "Item Name": "mango shake",
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1664",
    "Item Name": "apple juice",
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "2705",
    "Item Name": "strawybery  shake",
  },
]     same for others also the data format is same just names got changed

Comment: @sarah please help me out i am stuck here from long time :(

Comment: @dheerajkumar I am working on something for you. I think this will solve it but I will get back to you in a little while :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186916/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-sarah).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from our discussion in the comments I have come up with another solution to your problem.

Instead of generating a new table everytime a category is selected (and using local storage) you could display all category data in the table and then hide and show table rows depending on which category is selected.

This would mean that any quantity values selected by the user will stay in the input fields (even when the category is changed) as the input field will stay in the DOM.

You will firstly need to add the name of the category to each item in your JSON i.e

```
{ "Item Code": "1056", "Item Name": "banana shake", "category name": "juce"}
```

Then when the table is generated (in the `addTable` function) you add a class called `item-row` and also a class equal to the `"category name"` in the JSON (thus producing tr tags in a similar way to the following format):

```
<tr class="item-row juce">
```

Note: This is so we can target particular rows to dynamically add styling.

When a new category is selected you can dynamically add styling to the appropriate rows. The styling which we can use to hide and show table rows is the visibility property which we can set to either visible (to show a row) or collapse (to hide a row).

```
element.style.visibility = "visible";
```

OR

```
element.style.visibility = "collapse";
```

So with all that in mind your code will look as follows (i've commented where i've added code):

## addTable function

```
function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  var colNum = col.length; //to improve the speed
  for (var i = 0; i < colNum + 1; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    if (i >= colNum) {
      th.innerHTML = "Quantity";
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    } else {
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    //add a class called "item-row" to the table row so that we can target all item rows 
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length + 1; j++) {
      //add a class with the name of the category to each items row. This will be either juce, rice or roti etc. 
      var categoryName = tableData[i]["category name"];
      tr.classList.add(categoryName);

      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
      if (i > -1 && j >= colNum) {

        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "center";
        quantityField.setAttribute('name', 'Quantity');
        quantityField.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'on');
        quantityField.setAttribute('value', '0');
        quantityField.setAttribute('type', 'number');
        quantityField.setAttribute('required', 'required');
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      } else {

        if (tableData[i]['Item Code'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]['Item Name'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (j > 1)
          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
```

## The CategoryName onchange function

```
  $('#CategoryName').on('change', function() {
    var selectedOption = this.value;
    console.log(selectedOption);
    //get all item rows so we can target them.
    var itemRows = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");

    if(selectedOption === 'All'){
        //If "All" then style all rows with visibility: visible.
        for(var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++){
               itemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }else{
        //If the selectedOption is anything other than "All",
        //we firstly style all rows with visibility: collapse
        for(var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++){
            itemRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
        }
        //we then get all rows which have the selectedOption as a class and style those rows with visibility: visible.
        var selectedItemRows = document.getElementsByClassName(selectedOption);
        for(var i = 0; i < selectedItemRows.length; i++){
            selectedItemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
  });
```

Comment: hey if you get some free time please look at this qusetion i want to do somthing like this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402496/how-to-hide-html-table-rows-if-values-are-0/54403645#54403645]

Comment: if you get some time please check out this question once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846400/appended-new-row-is-not-behaving-like-previous-one-row

Answer (score 0):

You could use local storage to store a key/value pair.

Key/value pairs will stay in the browser until you remove them (i.e with `localStorage.clear()`).

Here is an idea on how you could use it in your project.

1. Everytime a user changes a quantity input field (without saving it) you store the value in local storage.
2. In order to do this you need to add a unique id attribute to each quantity input field e.g `id="Qty1056"`. (1056 being the item code). Then before setting the "value" attribute to 0 (e.g `quantityField.setAttribute('value', '0');`) you check local storage to see if a value is saved there from the last time the user changed the quantity for this item.
   (If no value exists in local storage then set the quantity value to 0.
   If a value exists in local storage for this item code then get the value and set the value of the quantity input field to it.)

I've added my new code to your full code. The code i've added is marked with the comment `//ADDING NEW CODE` and other comments.

Also, you can check whats in `localStorage` by visiting the `Application` tab in the `Developer tools` (I've attached a screenshot below the code).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //clear local storage. (Note: if you want the values to persist after u refresh browser then you should NOT clear local storage).
  localStorage.clear();
  //the rest of your (document).ready code goes here as normal
});

//Your addTable function. (It's mostly the same as you had. I've added comments where i've added code)
function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  var colNum = col.length; //to improve the speed
  for (var i = 0; i < colNum + 1; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    if (i >= colNum) {
      th.innerHTML = "Quantity";
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    } else {
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length + 1; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
      if (i > -1 && j >= colNum) {

        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "center";
        quantityField.setAttribute('name', 'Quantity');
        quantityField.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'on');
        quantityField.setAttribute('type', 'number');
        quantityField.setAttribute('required', 'required');
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");

        //ADDING CODE HERE
        //create a unique Id string for the quantity input field.
        //We will use a string e.g 'Qty' concantenated with the item code for this item (as it is unique).
        //So we will have something like 'Qty1056'
        var quantityIdString = 'Qty' + tableData[i]['Item Code'];
        //add the id attribute to the input field
        quantityField.setAttribute('id', quantityIdString);
        //check localStorage to see if a quantity value exists for this item code
        //the key will be something like 'Qty1056' (the same as the id of the quantity input field).
        if(localStorage.getItem(quantityIdString) === null){
          //this key does NOT exist in local storage 
          //therefore the user has not changed the value of this items quantity input field yet so set it to 0.
          quantityField.setAttribute('value', '0');
        }else{
          //this key DOES exist in local storage so get the value from local storage and 
          //set the value attribute of our quantity input field to it
          var quantityFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem(quantityIdString);  
          quantityField.setAttribute('value', quantityFromLocalStorage);    
        }
        //append the quantity field to the table cell
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);     
      } else {
        if (tableData[i]['Item Code'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]['Item Name'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (j > 1)
          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
    }
  }

  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
  //ADDING CODE HERE
  //Now that the table has been appended to the document we can add the listeners to the quantity input fields as follows.
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    ///log the item code to check it
    console.log(tableData[i]['Item Code']);
    //pass in the item code to the addQuantityFieldListener function
    addQuantityFieldListener(tableData[i]['Item Code']);
  }
}

//ADDING CODE HERE
function addQuantityFieldListener(itemCode){
  /* This function adds an "input" listener to a quantity input field to check when a new quantity value 
   * is selected/entered by the user for a particular item.
   * Each time a new quantity is selected/entered we store the new value in local storage. 
   */
  //form the quantityIdString which will also be the key of the item in local storage
  var quantityIdString = 'Qty' + itemCode;
  var quantityInputField = document.getElementById(quantityIdString);
  //we listen for the "input" event which will occur when a new quantity value is selected/entered by the user on this quantity input field. 
  quantityInputField.addEventListener("input", function(){
      //store the most recent quantity value for this item in local storage as follows:
      localStorage.setItem(quantityIdString, quantityInputField.value);
  });
}
```

## Screenshot of Application tab in developer tools (showing local storage key/value pairs)

[image]

Comment: I am facing some issue while adding this one to my code..when ever you ll be free please let me know please.

Comment: @dheerajkumar I'v changed my answer as I realize there was an issue. Please read it in full as it is quite different to before. Let me know if you've any problems

Comment: hey..your code really helped me,but i have a very small issue,whenever you ll get some free time please ping a comment here, i want to clear a small doubt

Comment: @dheerajkumar sure no probs. what is it? :)

Comment: hey now i am storing the values into local variable so on saving the form i want to save the table data into db..but currently it is saving the current page data only...like user enters somthing in juce and rice also and i am saving the data when rice option is clicked..it is only saving the rice data

Comment: Oh yea i know what you mean. That is because you are creating a new form/table when a new category is selected so when you save e.g the rice data, the juce data is not in your form/table/the DOM.

Comment: You can show me the code you have to save the data if you like. I will see if there is a way you could save the other data too..

Comment: yup thats the issue.its saving only current dom...i have my backend code in java which i am getting through request.getParameter .i want to save itemname item code and quantity entered by user thats it..but for all the categories user have entered the data

Comment: Actually i'm thinking now what might have been a better way to structure the code would be if you output the full table to the page with all categories and then when a new category is selected you just hide the table rows of the other categories through the use of a CSS class. That way the input values should stay in the form fields and you wouldn't need to store them in local storage. and then you also wouldn't have a problem with saving the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187276/discussion-between-sarah-and-dheeraj-kumar).